# Using Backbone sync with preexisting Javascript API

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm building a Backbone *framework* for a new programming language and I'm trying to adapt it to Backbone's sync instead of adapting Backbone to it.

I need to work with a pre-existing Javascript API which provides some abstractions and ultimately provides sync with server. Let's get an example:

Say I want to fetch a model and let's imagine this *framework* is already built. When I call `fetch()` on a model, which is the flow of function calls (and its parameters) and events until the model has its data? I know `fetch()` may have a parameter which is an object with options, but since I need to override this `fetch()` call I need to know what format Backbone expects `fetch()` to return and the same goes for `parse()` input parameter or `save()` call, and the events that are fired on each function.

I think I get that `parse()` expects an object as parameter which will be used to set the model with its data automatically, and that I should override it to build models and collections there, in case there's some model nesting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key to overriding Sync is to map "read", "create", "update" and "delete" actions to your API.  You will be passed an `options` object which has a `success` callback.  You need to call that `success` function when your API returns, with an object filled with properties.

This is the object that will ultimately be sent to `parse` to figure things out.

I recently went through this exercise to adapt SignalR to Backbone.Sync:

[Backbone.SignalR](https://github.com/SrtSolutions/backbone.signalr/blob/master/client/backbone.signalr.js)

I read the LocalStorage adapter for Backbone for inspiration:

[Backbone.LocalStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js)